# Unit test before pull merge failing to connect to database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, github, github-actions

I have set up a GitHub Actions workflow to run before merging a feature branch to main branch of my Laravel application

```yaml
name: Test before Merge
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
jobs:
  test:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test_root_password
          MYSQL_DATABASE: test_database
          MYSQL_USER: test_user
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: test_password
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up PHP
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: '8.1'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: composer install

      - name: Create .env file
        run: cp .env.ci .env

      - name: Generate application key
        run: php artisan key:generate

      - name: Migrate and seed database
        run: php artisan migrate:fresh --seed

      - name: Run PHPUnit
        run: vendor/bin/phpunit
```

The unit tests access and interact with MySQL database, whenever I run the test I get the error below:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as `name`, (data_length + index_length) as `size`, table_comment as `comment`, engine as `engine`, table_collation as `collation` from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'test_database' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)
```

Below is `env.ci` file data:

```bash
APP_KEY=
APP_ENV=local
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test_database
DB_USERNAME=test_user
DB_PASSWORD=test_password
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was fixed by changing the **DB_HOST=localhost** to **DB_HOST=127.0.0.1** in the .env.ci. I also changed the mysql version from `8.0` to `latest` on the github action yml

Also another error showed up after fixing the above relating to failing to connect to the database. In order to connect correctly to the MySQL database, In the phpunit.xml I removed the `<env name="DB_DATABASE" value="testing"/>` row so that the DB_DATABASE value is take from the .env in the Github Action